# Как задать кодировку при подключении к бд MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Добрый день, подключаюсь к БД таким образом:

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://172.0.0.1/klon";

private static final String user = "root";

private static final String password = "root";
```

Возник вопрос как можно задать кодировку UTF-8 сразу при подключении то есть сказать MySQL что данные будут поступать на русском?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кодировка задается в URL: `jdbc:mysql://172.0.0.1/klon?characterEncoding=utf8`